# Use of different fonts such as malayalam,hindi etc in a website

Tags: browser, fonts

I am new to PHP. I am developing a news website in different languages.I am using ML-TTKarthika font for malayalam. My problem is that this font is not supported in all browers (Chrome,Opera). How I solve this problem. In my site Hindi,Tamil fonts are also needed. Please  anyone give me an answer..Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at the below mentioned link:
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/193156/how-can-i-create-a-web-form-that-displays-and-accepts-tamil-language

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP

Answer (score 0):

This should help you: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp

Especially the Part "Using The Font You want"

Basically you can provide a Font with CSS:

```
@font-face
{
  font-family:myFirstFont;
  src:url(/path/to/font.woff);
}
```

And then use it:

```
body
{
  font-family:myFirstFont;
}
```